# how to crawl a content in host header site collection in sharepoint 2013

Tags: crawl, host-header

I created a host header site collection (ex: http://xyz.com). I went to content sources and added the http://xyz.com and did a full crawl after full crawl is done. when i go and search anything in the host header site collection i get only http://xyz.com has the search result.

why is it getting only the url i put it in the content source. i want it to get crawled all the items under that site collection and display the results in the search result page.

As of now i get only the same url i put in the content search in Central Administration.

Even in the crawl log i see only the url i put in content search is crawled.

how do i make all the content in the site collection to get crawled.

Answer (score 2):

A root site collection is a requirement for any Web application and furthermore it is also necessary for crawling content. 
This root site collection must have the same URL as the Web application.
Only the root site collection of the web application appears in the content source. 
All the other host-named site collections in the web application do not appear in the content source and as such by default search automatically crawls the other host-named site collections.
Hence in your case although you have setup a HNSC (host name site collection) you need to ensure that you are inserting the URL of your web application (which would also have a root site collection which can be blank as well!!) in the content source of your Search Service Application and remove this site collection URL that you have currently put in over there.

Perform a INDEX RESET and then perform a FULL CRAWL to check the search results thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made user all the "start addresses" are added to the list of links to be crawled? [Check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtjkBFVc35M)... it does a pretty good job in explaning :)

Comment: Have you made user all the "start addresses" are added to the list of links to be crawled??? what does it mean ? i watched the video he added fileshare location in content search in the same way i addded my hostheadersitecollection http://xyz.com in the content search and did a full crawl. but no use. it is crawling http://xyz.com and when i go to site collection and search for anything it is showing on ly this http://xyz.com result in search result web part.